# How to keep table confined with in outer fieldset without hard-coding height in pixels

Tags: overflow, css-position, css-tables, fieldset

My html page has a fieldset and inside that div I am rendering a table on the fly.
This table can have just 1 row or 1000 row.

Outer Div's height is 75% and I do not want table to go pass through that.

The HTML code looks like this

```
<fieldset>
    <div>Some text and some HTML Elements </div>
    <<h4>Field Permissions </h4>
    <table class="mytable">
        // Dynamically populate rows. Number of rows can be 1 or 100 or 1000
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Now, I wish to keep this table within outer field set but it renders past across the field set.

In the attached image, DOM element with red border is the table and with blue border is the outer fieldset.
[image]

This is my css:

```
.mytable{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried : overflow:auto; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh wait. If i remove 'position: absolute' and it works. 
Thank you all for help though

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow:auto; to the fieldset

```
fieldset{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: you mean to fieldset cause table expands and do not scroll

Comment: .mytable{
    overflow:auto;
} ... I tried this.. It doesnt work

Comment: Edited my answer to GCyrillus' comment. Try it now

Comment: any chance we can get a sample of the code in jsfiddle?